# Debugging file referenced by the other host with PhpStorm, Xdebug and Vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, homestead

I have got php website on one host and the project which is placed on Vagrant Homestead virtual machine. I want to debug only that project which is placed on the local virtual machine. If i type it's exactly name which I have declared previously in Homestead.yaml file I can debug it. But there is a problem because it is not a standalone site but a module to main site. The main site sends POST to my module and this module return some data to it. How should I config my PhpStorm to accept debug connection from that module, not from the main site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem! 
It is impossible to debug case which i described at the top. You have to catch POST and GET methods, decide which you are interested in, and use it on site you want to debug. You can make it using "Postman":
http://www.getpostman.com/apps
I suggest You to use postman for Windows because it will not overwrite Your origin in Post method.